# How to get rid of annoying white box at the top of my website

Tags: html, css

I was just starting to code a website (with a little background knowledge) and when designing the header I noticed that it was not touching the top of the page. Just wondering if anyone knew how to fix this.

Website Picture:

[image]

HTML Code:

```css
    body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }
    h1{
    background: black;
    color: blue;
    }
    red{
    color:red;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Test Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css">
    <h1>---The <red>Test</red> Website</h1>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your HTML is thoroughly  invalid. Fix that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update you css with the below code. Instead of body{margin:0; padding:0} put *{margin:0; padding:0}

```
Remove this  -->  body{margin:0; padding:0;}

Add this     -->  *{margin:0; padding:0;}
```

Comment: this will remove margins from every single element, including paragraphs and headings, which you usually want.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes html has padding too.

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```